# How to scale a website so that it show same visible area for all viewports?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

I made an website for an viewport 1366px*768px . Now I want that when I resize my browser then it should show same website in mobile or bigger screen without breaking design,I don't want responsive website .

Example :

1. when I open website in 360px*420px viewport then my website get scale down and show exact  visible area as in 1366px*768px without any scroll bar .
2. when I open website in 2000px*1000px viewport then my website get scale up and show exact  visible area as in 1366px*768px without any extra space .

I tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1366, initial-scale=1" />

 const siteWidth = 1366;
      const scale = screen.width / siteWidth;
      document
        .querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]')
        .setAttribute(
          'content',
          'width=' + siteWidth + ', initial-scale=' + scale + ''
        );
    }
```

By using above code I am able to scale website according to the width i.e 1366px on mobile device but on changing height it is showing extra space or scroll bar at the bottom. Also it is not working in desktop.

Any good solution so that I can scale my website correctly for all viewports?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to happen when the aspect ratio of your new viewport is different from the aspect ratio of your original design? I cannot see how it can avoid having blank space somewhere.

Comment: @AHaworth, I got it aspect ratio need to be same for viewport otherwise it will cause issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution down below works, but you need to consider removing scrollbars or make fine adjustments to add scrollbars to scale.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- All other elements should be here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
}
```

```
const siteWidth = 1366;
const scale = window.innerWidth / siteWidth;

document.querySelector(".container").style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
```

Comment: I think align-items: flex-start; will become align-items: center.

Comment: Not a big deal. As long as it's scaled properly, it will be placed in the same position. I think it would be better to put the content at the top of the viewport when it is displayed on portrait screens.